# FastAPI SQLAlchemy connect to database during runtime

Tags: python, server, sqlalchemy, runtime, fastapi

I have an application in FastAPI using SQLAlchemy. I already have a database setup, however, I want to access another database during runtime. Can I create a second instance of it? The URL will be provided while the server is running. I tried searching online but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The following post seems to have solved my problem! for anyone else looking.

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-SQLAlchemy

Just the same way you connect to one. Example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker 
 
db1 = create_engine('postgresql://user1:password1@host1/dbname1') 
db2 = create_engine('mysql://user2:password2@host2/dbname2') 
DB1Session = sessionmaker(db1) 
DB2Session = sessionmaker(db2) 
db1session = DB1Session() 
db2session = DB2Session() 
 
db1session.query(Whatever)... 
db2session.query(AnythingElse)... 
 
db2session.commit() 
db1session.rollback()
```

The two engines, and the two session makers wrapping them, are distinct and independent, you can use them at will. SQLAlchemy does not care how many different databases you are talking to, simultaneously.

Your table metadata and mappers may be bound to an engine directly, MetaData(bind=someengine), so if you do reflection or table creation or such, you may need to specify the engine explicitly. E.g. to create the same table in two databases:

```
db1meta = MetaData(db1) 
mytable = Table('mytable', db1meta, Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)) 
mytable.create() # creates it in db1, the default for its metadata object 
mytable.create(bind=db2) # creates it in db2, overriding the default 
mytable.create(bind=db1session.connection()) 
# last line creates the table in db1 with transactional DDL 
# (works in PostgreSQL), so the table creation will be rolled 
# back if the transaction is rolled back.
```

Comment: Please include any relevant details _in your answer_. A link only answer have issues where the external link can disappear, the relevant might not be available to those that reads the answer and it will not be archived in the archive.